# iPhone 4s restore. number of errors

Tags: itunes, ios, iphone, restore

I have an iphone 4s i just restored it and am running at 6.1.3 (latest version) I backed up my phone before the restore and have restored from the correct backup. I now have two problems:

1. I want to redownload all my apps from the store but when i access the app store and find an app I have previously bought this happens: E.G Instagram I search for Instagram and then where it should say install in that little curved edge box, it just says open. So I thought OH good I still have it downloaded! so I click on open and literally nothing happens. I click it a few more times. Still nothing! I am beyond confused. The same happens with all the apps that I have previously owned: Snapchat, Twitter, Facebook ETC.
2. all my music; the iphone recognises all my playlists and artists and all the albums and tells me their all on my phone but when i click on songs, there is nothing there absoultly nothing. And when I go to artist and clikc on artists to find a song, there will be nothing inside them. And the same happens in albums.

I have never done anything like jailbreaking or modifying my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> General -> Reset -> Erase All Content and Settings.  Then when prompt to choose between `set up as new iphone` and `restore from icloud/itunes backup`, choose restore from itunes.

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you backed up your iPhone via iTunes before the update, restore form the same backup using iTunes once again:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1766

After the restore, make sure you fully sync your iTunes library (with all Sync options from all tabs checked). This should resolve the issue.